# Symfony 2 - Sonata Admin Role based security

Tags: security, symfony, acl, symfony-sonata

With Sonata, I'm trying to use the role based security.

I want to give a group, rights for listing, editing & creating users, so I created a role with

```
ROLE_MANAGE_USERS:
    - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_EDIT
    - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST
    - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_CREATE
```

This works fine, but according to the [doc](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration), I'm understanding that a user granted with

```
ROLE_SONATA_USER_STAFF
```

Should already inherit rights for `[EDIT, LIST, CREATE]`, but that does not seem to be the case

I also tried with

```
ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_STAFF
```

Is there something I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's not the case. First of all, the name of the main roles for edit depends on the services names. For example, if the service of the admin is `sonata.user.admin`, then the roles will be, for example:

```
ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_LIST
ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_VIEW
```

As you can see, the prefix is always `ROLE` (symfony 2 requirement), followed by the service name (but having the dots exchanged with underscores, and all capital letters), and ended with the prefix for the specific permission:

- LIST: view the list of objects
- VIEW: view the detail of one object
- CREATE: create a new object
- EDIT: update an existing object
- DELETE: delete an existing object
- EXPORT: (for the native Sonata export links)

As I can understand, there is no ROLE_SONATA_USER_STAFF predefined for edit, list and create. However, you can define it in the hierarchy, in the security.yml file:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        # Setting up 
        ROLE_SONATA_USER_STAFF:
            - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_EDIT
            - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_LIST
            - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_CREATE
        # using the staff role to create new roles
        ROLE_MANAGE_USERS:             [ROLE_SONATA_USER_STAFF]
```

Comment: I see, I was not getting that it was given as an example.